# Undefined index: attribute_price error after update from 1.7.7.5 to 1.7.7.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After the update from 1.7.7.5 to 1.7.7.7 the error 'Undefined index: attribute_price' appears.

It fails on line 3418 (1.7.7.7) in Product.php.
`'attribute_price' => $row['attribute_price'] ?: null,`

Bevore line 3408 (1.7.7.5) there was this code that works:
`'attribute_price' => (isset($row['attribute_price']) ? $row['attribute_price'] : null),`

It fails only if the feature Combination is disabled.

I don't understand because this code works in the same environment:

```
$array2 = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];

echo $array2['foos'] ?: "gugus";
```

- PrestaShop version: 1.7.7.7
- PHP version: 7.2.24 on Ubuntu

Comment: Maybe you have an override active which does not work with the updated version? Did you try to disable the overrides to see if the issue still persist?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a core bug to me..

They changed the previous correct statement to the shorthand operator **?:** (that states for if...else) without considering that if **Combination::isFeatureActive()** is not active, **$row['attribute_price']** is not set in the query :

```
        if (Combination::isFeatureActive()) {
            $sql->select('IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute,0) id_product_attribute, product_attribute_shop.`price` AS attribute_price, product_attribute_shop.default_on, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax` AS attribute_ecotax');
            $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute_shop', 'product_attribute_shop', '(product_attribute_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = ' . (int) $id_shop . ')');
        } else {
            $sql->select('0 as id_product_attribute');
        }
```

You can edit ?: to ?? or restore the 1.7.7.5 code to avoid the notice.